Does any one know how to solve this error I am having? Says 'VSPKg packet did not load correctly'
!VSPKg Packet Error](https://i.sstatic.net/WjSsHXwX.png)
I updated DevExpress extension in Visual Studios to v23.2.5 and ever since then there has been an erroring loading up every time I close down Visual Studios and reopen it (see image). I have scoured the internet for a solution but come up with nothing. Just wondering if anyone has a trick or a solution to solve this for me. Relatively new to coding so forgive me.

This problem can occur for a variety of reasons, including a corrupt extension, a configuration problem, or a conflict with other installed extensions. You could try to take the following steps to resolve this issue:
1.Check the ActivityLog.xml file for any errors related to the DevExpress extension.
2.Sometimes repairing Visual Studio can fix issues with extensions.
Open the Visual Studio Installer.
Find your installed version of Visual Studio.
Click on "More" and then "Repair".
3.Uninstall and then reinstall the DevExpress extension:
Go to Extensions > Manage Extensions.
Find the DevExpress extension in the list of installed extensions.
Click "Uninstall" and restart Visual Studio if prompted.
After restarting, go back to Extensions > Manage Extensions, search for the DevExpress extension, and install it again.
4.Reset Visual Studio Settings
Open Visual Studio.
Go to Tools > Import and Export Settings.
Select "Reset all settings" and click "Next".
Choose whether to save your current settings or not.
Select a default collection of settings and click "Finish".
5.Conflicts with other extensions can cause issues. Try disabling other extensions to see if the problem resolves.
6.Clear Visual Studio Cache
Close Visual Studio.
Delete the contents of the following folders (make a backup if necessary).
